# What to do when "apt-get update" gets stuck in 100%?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, ruby, apt-get

I'm setupping a VirtualBox VM to do my development work with Ruby on Rails.

My problem is that `apt-get update` is taking *very* long, ~30 minutes instead of seconds.

I can install things with `apt-get install`, but cannot install a Ruby version with [RVM](https://rvm.io/), because it runs `apt-get update` before every Ruby installation.

How can I fix `apt-get`? Or install Ruby skipping `apt-get update`?

Comment: It sounds like you're having connectivity issues with the servers. You can try to generate a better `/etc/apt/sources.list` file using this: http://repogen.simplylinux.ch Be sure to backup your current list first in case this messes it up even more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a network problem.

But I found a workaround:

- Used aptitude instead of apt-get to install rbenv dependencies:

> sudo aptitude install autoconf bison build-essential libssl-dev libyaml-dev libreadline6-dev zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libffi-dev libgdbm3 libgdbm-dev

- Used [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#installing-ruby-versions) instead of [RVM](https://rvm.io/) to install Ruby